# negative regex for perl string substitution

Tags: regex, perl, substitution, negation

I'm trying to shorten all multiple spaces to one space, except for the first occurence of spaces (indentation).

I've found that this code will replace the first occurences:

`$_ =~ s/^ +/ /;`

So I thought, its negation will do what I want. But it does not:

`$_ =~ s/!^ +/ /g;`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change approach to the regex

```
s/\S\K +/ /g;
```

Comment: Non space, keep it, followed by one or more spaces, replace with space. (and the bit you kept). I think? But a nice solution.

Comment: nice idea, yes or `(?<=\S) +`

Comment: Yes, \K is positive look behind from v5.10 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

Exclamation mark is not negation in regex. At least, not like that.

What you need is negative lookbehind:

```
s/(?<!^)\s+/ /g;
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Yes. It matches any whitespace. Easy enough to be more selective though.